# A term/phrase/idiom for unknowingly asking about someone's bad news

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Examples:

```
you: How's the job?
them: ...I got fired.
```

or:

```
you: How's your mom doing? *enthusiastically*
them: ...she passed away.
```

What would you call that? This happens a lot, and it's always awkward.

Comment: Not sure if there's a single term since there are underlying factors such as whether or not the asker already knows the answer and is provoking the askee - but in the absence of malice, you might say that it is a case of unintentionally putting your foot in your mouth.

Comment: That's sometimes known as "putting your foot in it".  (With "it" being your mouth or a pile of excrement, same difference.)

Comment: A "quagmire" ? (*an awkward, complex, or embarrassing situation*)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can call it a ***[gaffe](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gaffe):***

> - a socially awkward or tactless act

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

The first word that comes to mind is to ***blunder***.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other excellent answers (*'gaffe'* and *'blunder'*) one might also reach for the French, *'faux pas'*.  Alternately you might consider *'solicism'* although it's relatively little known and frankly not as good as the three aforementioned.

From Webster's Third New International Dictionary:

> faux pas noun plural faux pas
>   Etymology: French, literally, false step
>   blunder; especially a social blunder

There is also (and I have to admit the thesaurus delivered this one) *'infelicity'*.

From Webster's Third New International Dictionary:

> infelicity noun
>   Etymology: Middle English infelicite, from Latin infelicitas, from infelic-, infelix unfortunate, unhappy (from in- in- (I) + felic-, felix fruitful, happy) + -itas -ity — more at feminine
>   1. the quality or state of being infelicitous:
>   a. unhappiness, wretchedness, misfortune
>   confusion and infelicity of her emotions — Elinor Wylie
>   b. lack of suitableness or appropriateness
>   2. something (as an act or word) that is infelicitous
>   examined for infelicities before printing — E.P.Cheyney

*'Infelicity'* or *'infelicitous'* has the curious character of likely provoking it's own context, thus:

"Infelicity."
"What! In Who?!"
"Yes, a perfect example."